# Even if i dont call super() in subclass the program throws error as Must define an explicit constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, super

Here im calling the parameterized  constuctor of  base class but when i didnt give a default constructor in base class it throws error why is that so since im not calling super()

```
class Base {
  int num;
   //  if i didnt give this default constructor then throws error
  //     Base(){}
      Base(int a)
        { 
        num=a; 
        } 
       int getnum()
        {  
        return num; 
        }
 }

class sub1 extends Base{
     sub1(){
        super(5);  // im not calling super();
     }
   }
   class Sub2 extends Base{

   public static void main(String[] args) {

  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is in `Sub2` class, here the super is not called

Comment: sub1 is fine. either sub2 needs its parent to have a zero-arg constructor, or it needs to call super with a int argument. seems like you may have misunderstood the error message?

Answer (score 2):

When you override a class that has a constructor with arguments you must call that constructor. If the super class has more than 1 constructor with args you must call at least 1 of them.

You are in fact calling super in sub1 but not sub2. When referring to a constructor the definition is the following.

```java
super(argument, argument2, etc);
```

Where as calling a super method is;

```java
super.method(argument, argument2);
```